Significance of Line in LD GNU Linker Command Language
I am trying to decipher the LD GNU linker command language. In my linker script, what is the significance of the bolded line? Obviously, I expect it to give a FLASH memory location, but don't understand what the ".)" part means in relation to a FLASH address. I've reviewed the Command Language manual from GNU but still am not getting it.
/* Main application access to the bootloader API */
.linkToBootloaderAPI LINK_TO_BOOTLOADER_START : ALIGN (4)
{
    PROVIDE(__link_to_bootloader_api_start = .);
    KEEP (*(.linkToBootloaderAPI))
} >rom

APP_BUILD_INFO_SECTION_OFFSET   =   0x20;
PROVIDE(__linktobootloaderapi_size = . - __link_to_bootloader_api_start);
**PROVIDE(__bootloader_end_address = .);**
PROVIDE(__bootloader_rom_usage = ALIGN(CY_FLASH_ROW_SIZE));
PROVIDE(__app_build_info_address = ALIGN(CY_FLASH_ROW_SIZE)+APP_BUILD_INFO_SECTION_OFFSET);

EDIT: Can't get the line to bold. I mean PROVIDE(__bootloader_end_address = .);

.) is not a single token, here.  The line is PROVIDE(), with a parameter of __bootloader_end_address = . - in other words, an assignment of . (the current location) to the given name.

@jasonharper In the example above, do I understand correctly that I have to scroll up in my linker script and find the last time the "." was assigned to an actual address, and that will be the assigned address for __bootloader_end_address (assuming no other changes were made)?

Every time a section is copied to the output (such as via a KEEP()), it goes at the current address in ., and . is then updated to the next address after the copied section.

To explain PROVIDE(__bootloader_end_address = .); we are calling the PROVIDE "function" with symbol "__bootloader_end_address" and assigning it value of "." which causes a the linker to know about this symbol and accept it in code it will encounter even though it does not know the address of the symbol yet.
To try and explain more why is it done, it is to define a symbol called __bootloader_end_address before that symbol has been defined. The compiler/linker on first/early pass can know symbols are defined but does not know explicit address for them, the linker has the job of resolving symbols on a later  pass when linking code together.
See https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/PROVIDE.html
To understand the ".)" part, I think you're confused about the syntax.
It's like a function call with c syntax.
; - denotes command separator - end of command
PROVIDE(parameter) - is the function call
PROVIDE(paramname = defaultvalue) - function call with one parameter paramname and giving it a default value of defaultvalue.
